# How to add Hyperlink in javascript var?

Tags: javascript, html, var

I've leraned js for a few days

as topic
I want to put several hyperlinks in a var

```
var aaa = [
'www.google.com',
'www.yahoo.com',
'www.facebook.com'];

$('#showlink').text(aaa[2]);
```

and then
"www.yahoo.com" link will show in html,it's an url

```
<div id="showlink"> </div>
```

how can i do for that?

Comment: in place of only URL you need to put complete anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jQuery .html() function instead of .text() which allows you to dynamically update HTML, so;

```
$('#showlink').html('<a href="' + aaa[2] + '">' + aaa[2] + '</a>');
```

OR, you can append to the DIV with:

```
$('#showlink').append('<a href="' + aaa[2] + '">' + aaa[2] + '</a>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code

```
$("<a/>",{"href":"http://"+aaa[2],"text":aaa[2]}).appendTo("#showlink");
```

Comment: Please explain the OP that what does your code do and why OP need this code ;).

Comment: @shA.t this is simple. $('<a/>') creates a Anchor Node, with Text as the stored string in array. This also appends "http://" before URL string and makes that as href attribute. That anchor tag with text and href, then gets appended to "#showlink" div.

Comment: We are here to make a royal programming reference, thanks ;).

Answer (score 0):

Add a button at your `div` like this

```
<div id="showlink"> </div>
<input type="button" id="gen" />
```

and use `click()` function in your `js` like this

```
$("#gen").click(function() {

   var aaa = [
'www.google.com',
'www.yahoo.com',
'www.facebook.com'];

 $("#showlink").val(aaa[2]);

});
```